3x3 grids with black dots
Initially I thought the pattern involved shifting each dot by 1 3 spaces alternating on each turn - this is not an option.

Any help?

Hi dk30 welcome to PSE. Could you provide proper attribution to the puzzle by telling us it’s source?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

I got the answer btw just waiting for a source

Hi dk30 welcome to PSE. I may very well also have an answer awaiting a source :)

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/FinancialCareers/comments/194cpdq/could_you_guys_help_me_with_the_following_test/
